# Trouble using function name as argument in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I wanted to make it easier to change a certain function which will be used by a subroutine in a fortran project. However I can not get it to work. I have seen quite a few examples which use the `external`, however I am not sure if I have to use it, since I put all my function and subroutines in modules.

Here is a simplified example of the problem I am dealing with:

I have the program in a separate file:

```
program test
    use Parameters
    use circArrayConstructer
    use velocity
    use RungeKutta4
    implicit none
    integer(is) :: N, P, nsteps, i, j
    real(fd)    :: D, dt
    real(fd),    allocatable :: coor(:,:)
    integer(is), allocatable :: topo(:,:)
    integer(is) :: error
    read (*,*) D, nsteps, N, P
    dt = 1.0 / nsteps
    call circArray ( 0.5_fd, 0.5_fd, 0.2_fd, 0.2_fd, N, coor, topo, error )
    do i = 1, P
        do j = 1, nsteps
            if ( mod(P,2) > 0 ) then
                call RK4 ( dt, coor, D, vel1, coor )
            else
                call RK4 ( dt, coor, D, vel2, coor )
            end if
        end do
    end do
end program test
```

I put each subroutine and all the functions in a separate module and each module has its own file:
The module `Parameters` just defines constants and variable types:

```
module Parameters
    implicit none
    integer, parameter  :: fs = selected_real_kind(6)
    integer, parameter  :: fd = selected_real_kind(15)
    integer, parameter  :: is = selected_int_kind(9)
    integer, parameter  :: id = selected_int_kind(18)
    real(fd), parameter :: PI = 3.141592653589793
end module Parameters
```

Module `circArrayConstructer` contains the subroutine `circArray` which has the output `error`, `coor` and `topo`, the last two have dimensions `N` by 2 and since `N` in an input they have to be allocated.

Module `RungeKutta4` contains the subroutine `RK4` which is an implementation of the 4th order Runge Kutta method:

```
module RungeKutta4
    use Parameters
    use velocity
    implicit none
    contains
        subroutine RK4 ( dt, coorOld, D, vel, coorNew )
            implicit none
            real(fd), intent(in ) :: dt
            real(fd), intent(in ) :: D
            real(fd), intent(in ) :: coorOld(:,:)
            real(fd), intent(out) :: coorNew(:,:)
            real(fd), dimension(size(coorOld,1), size(coorOld,2)) :: k1, k2, k3, k4
            real(fd), external    :: vel

            k1 = vel ( coorOld                , D )
            k2 = vel ( coorOld + 0.5 * dt * k1, D )
            k3 = vel ( coorOld + 0.5 * dt * k2, D )
            k4 = vel ( coorOld +       dt * k3, D )
            coorNew = coorOld + dt / 6.0 * (k1 + 2 * (k2 + k3) + k4)
        end subroutine RK4
end module RungeKutta4
```

And module `velocity` contains multiple functions:

```
module velocity
    use Parameters
    implicit none
    contains
        function vel1 ( coor, D )
            implicit none
            real(fd), intent(in) :: D
            real(fd), intent(in) :: coor(:,:)
            real(fd), dimension(size(coor,1), size(coor,2)) :: vel1
            vel1(:,1) = -2.0 * D * coor(:,2) * sin(PI * coor(:,1)) * cos(PI * coor(:,2) ** 2)
            vel1(:,2) = D * cos(PI * coor(:,1)) * sin(PI * coor(:,2) ** 2)
        end function vel1

        function vel2 ( coor, D )
            implicit none
            real(fd), intent(in) :: D
            real(fd), intent(in) :: coor(:,:)
            real(fd), dimension(size(coor,1), size(coor,2)) :: vel2
            vel2(:,1) = 2.0 * D * (1 - coor(:,2)) * sin(PI * coor(:,1)) * cos(PI * (1 - coor(:,2)) ** 2)
            vel2(:,2) = D * cos(PI * coor(:,1)) * sin(PI * (1 - coor(:,2)) ** 2)
        end function vel2
end module velocity
```

Currently when I try to compile the program I get the error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure 'vel': Type/rank mismatch in function result.

I have tried all kinds of things, such as changing the declaration of `vel` in `RungeKutta4` to `real(fd), external :: vel(:,:)` but that gives conflicting attributes. But I have run out of ideas on how to make the code work.

Comment: Have you tried using an `if` statement to select which velocity update to use?

Comment: I assume you mean inside the RK4 subroutine, if so then yes, that is what I used previous code and worked. But would like to make it easier to add more velocity functions for the future. So I thought it would be easiest to define which velocity function I would like to use in the call of the RK4 subroutine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the function in a module, you don't want to use `external`.  The problem is that RK4 doesn't know the properties of the function that it is receiving.  You can declare the function with an `interface` block:

```
interface
   function vel ( corr, D )
      import fd
      real (fd), intent (in) :: D
      real (fd), intent (in) :: corr (:,:)
      real(fd), dimension(size(corr,1), size(corr,2)) :: vel
   end function vel
end interface
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. And it also make kind of sense, since using external seemed a strange choice because modules should make them unnecessary, but at first did not know how else to declare the function (I thought interfaces where only for programs).